# What's the correct address of SNX?

Tags: tokens, addresses, synthetix

That is, the address of the token used as collateral in the [Synthetix](https://www.synthetix.io/) ecosystem.

I found two addresses:

- [0xC011A72400E58ecD99Ee497CF89E3775d4bd732F](http://etherscan.io/address/0xC011A72400E58ecD99Ee497CF89E3775d4bd732F)
- [0xC011a73ee8576Fb46F5E1c5751cA3B9Fe0af2a6F](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc011a73ee8576fb46f5e1c5751ca3b9fe0af2a6f)

The former is used by MetaMask and Etherscan and has a logo, but the latter is used by Uniswap and is deployed more recently.